# the field name is not known details errorkind crystall report

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I'm using VS2019,CR13 I'm trying to print records in crystall report between two times from timeprint filed
[this my access database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qeoU.png)

```
 rpt.Load("CrystalReport1.rpt")
        Dim myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
        Dim myLogin As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        For Each myTable In rpt.Database.Tables
            myLogin = myTable.LogOnInfo
            myLogin.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Application.StartupPath & "\NewIraqDB.mdb"
            myLogin.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "admin"
            myLogin.ConnectionInfo.Password = "723"
            myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myLogin)
        Next
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{table1.locationP}='" & a & "' and {table1.dateW}>='" & c1 & "' and {table1.dateW}<='" & c2 & "' and  {table1.timeprint}>='" & time1.Value.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") & "' and {table1.timeprint}<='" & time2.Value.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") & "'                                                                        "
        Else
            rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{table1.locationP}='" & a & "' and {table1.dateW}>='" & c1 & "' and {table1.dateW}<='" & c2 & "'"
        End If
        print1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        print1.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        print1.ShowDialog()
```

problem with RecordSelectionFormula line error in timeprint
[This image shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Nfn.png)

Comment: You need all fields, referenced in selection formula also present on report itself. They can be suppressed of course.

Comment: @Arvo thank you for replying when i remove                                     `{table1.timeprint}>='" & time1.Value.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") & "' and {table1.timeprint}<='" & time2.Value.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") & "`                               from RecordSelectionFormula it run without problem

Comment: And do you have this `{table1.timeprint}` field visible on report itself?